# Missing tags from html doc using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am web scraping from IMDB and I am trying to get the age rating of an episode of a show. When inspecting the website, [you can see the certificate tag here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF3cv.png). However when I use beautiful soup and print the html doc, [the span is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PUVa.png). (Note, I know the values in the screenshots are not the same, but the problem is the fact that the certificate is missing, its the same for all the items in the doc)

Here is the code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=tv_episode&num_votes=600,&sort=user_rating,desc&start=1&ref_=adv_nxt"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

data = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'lister-item mode-advanced'})
print(data)
```

Anyone know what I can do to fix this issue or the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** *Your question is not quite clear, cause the posted HTML in your images could not be compared, cause they are totally different (e.g. runtime 24 and 38 minutes) and also missing the details to identify - In new code use `find_all()` instead of old syntax `findAll()`*

Anyway, it cannot be assumed that all information is still available, so it should always be checked for existence. The following lines should show the elements that do not have the corresponding class in your selection:

```
url = "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=tv_episode&num_votes=600,&sort=user_rating,desc&start=1&ref_=adv_nxt"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

for e in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'lister-item mode-advanced'}):
    if e.find('span', attrs={'class': 'certificate'}) == None:
        print(e)
```